# Can't ask a question on SO with Chrome

Tags: support, status-completed, asking-questions

*I had to submit this with firefox*

I've not experienced any problem asking questions until today. When I submit my question, it claims I don't have any valid tags provided. But I do. "php markdown css" are all valid tags, yet the page continues to clear the tags field, and claim I have no valid values when I attempt to submit a question.

Anybody else experiencing this right now other than me? I'm noticing also that the font-color is not changing to a darker (black) color when I focus on the field. This suggests to me that there's a js-issue at the heart of this.

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37201/title-is-lost-the-first-time-you-try-to-post-a-question

Comment: We were finally able to repro this - a fix will be deployed tonight.

Comment: A dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37111/is-stackoverflow-ask-question-page-broken-in-google-chrome-latest-developer-versi

Comment: @JarrodDixon: Could you post an answer with a small explanation so I can accept?

Comment: Answered... I can haz rep? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out, it was a javascript issue - we were using the wrong event handler when capturing key presses.

Switching our script to use the `keydown` event, instead of `keypress`, solved the problem.

Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: +1/ACC Thanks for the quick response, Jarrod!

Answer (score 2):

A **lot** of people seem to have intermittent problems with SO on Chrome; I've had two "events" today where I've had to empty the browser cache, which always fixes it (for me, at least).

The suspicion is that the script files are cached in a corrupt state, breaking everything. Empty the cache and try again. We really should report these issues to the Chrome boards at some point... I'm not sure SO can do much about cache corruption.

Comment: Is it happening on other websites too? If not then it's probably not chrome's fault

Comment: @Koper - there are other sites?

Answer (score 1):

Are ypu using the stable or the developer build? The developer builds are known to cause exactly this (and other) problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting it in, rather than typing it in. That "fixed" it for me on Safari (yes, I had this problem too, on a non-chrome browser!)

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me after I tried to paste something in. The text is grey. I had to delete it to start typing again. After I try to submit..it gives me the error your reporting.

I'm not using a dev build.